# Create a test case for curl httprequest

Tags: php, curl, phpunit, httprequest, testcase

PHPUnit has [methods](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html) to test databases virtually, but how can I test an HTTP service like curl?

My class method gets a URL and requests parameters to send to server. It receives the answer as json and sends this json to another method to parse and return.

I want to create a PHPUnit test case for this class method. Should I provide a real url to my server? Should the server return a successful/error message to this test case?

Comment: use guzzle as httpclient. Have a feature for mock call

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the `curl` connection inside some methods of your class, wrap the `curl` call in it's own class, mock it, and have it passed to your class.

This way you can test the happy path by having the mock returns the real `json`, and also simulate curl errors (make the mock behaves like the real `curl` library).

Same applies for the parsing part. If you move the parsing code to it's own class and have it injected to the "main" class, then you'll be able to mock it, and simulate parsing errors.

For unit testing you should never do real network calls.

Comment: Thanks, as about your first paragraph, do you mean to not call curl directly in testcase but have it as a separate class and call it inside tescase? Please clarify by some sample codes what exactly you mean.